# Is it possible to run a MySQL request with this structure?

Tags: php, mysql, automation

```
    include("connect.php");
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[username]);


    function updateData($key){
    $field = "$$key";
    if($field == "") {
    } else {
    $sql= "UPDATE users SET $key = '$field' WHERE username ='$username'";
    mysql_query ( $sql , $conexion );
    }
    }

    updateData('password');
    updateData('firstname');
```

What I'm trying to make is an automatic way for this PHP file to recognize the fields and not save them if the input field value is empty.

If I mannually put the name of the field on the `$key` spaces, it works, but once I turn it into a function an run it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't write your code like this.

- For starters, it's not readable - it makes whoever is maintaining the code have to go find this function to figure out where the data being used is coming from.
- Secondly, you'll run into issues with variable scope - inside the function, none of your variables are defined unless you reference them with the `global` keyword to bring them into scope.

Instead, write your function like this:

```
function updateData($username, $key, $value){
    if($key != "" && $value != "") {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET $key = '$value' WHERE username ='$username'";
        mysql_query($sql, $conexion);
    }
}
```

and pass in the relevant values; that's what function arguments are designed for. You might also want to consider escaping the contents of the arguments before interpolating them.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem , its that variables `$username` ,  `$sql` , `$conexion` not recognize in this function

look on this link [variables scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: I have defined the `$username`, `$sql` and `$conexion` variables, but I thought it wouldn't be relevant to include them in my question code. But I have added them now. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, but functions have different variable *scopes*, hence why you have to use the `global` keyword if you want to bring outside variables into them. Why not just write your function to be called like this instead? `updateData('password', $password);`

Comment: AH! I think I understand what you mean now! THank you! I will try it and come back to you.

Comment: It worked but I had to get a little help from @Amber. Thank you very much for both's help.